# Unrecognized command raisebox. Which package should I install for it?

Tags: tables, graphics, errors, packages

I have a table that contains the word "bar" in column 1, and a picture of a drink in column 2. The picture is offset a little vertically, so I want to bring it down a bit. So, I used the `raisebox` command, but it gives the following error:

`Undefined control sequence. ... Bar & \raisebox{\0.2cm}\includegraphics`

Otherwise the code works fine. So, which package do I install for resolving this issue? I thought it should be under `graphicx`. I also tried `graphicx`, but to no avail. And I also searched online for which package to install to get raisebox to work, but I found no relevant solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  \bf Locale & \bf Index  \\ 
            \hline \rule[-2ex]{0pt}{5.5ex}  Bar & \raisebox{\-0.2cm}\includegraphics[]{index_bar.png} \\ 
            \hline 
\end{tabular}     
\end{document}
```

The output below is shown when I remove the `raisebox`:

[image]

Comment: `\raisebox` is a LaTeX command. You have the error `\0.2cm`, that's the error. It should read `0.2cm`

Comment: There are braces missing. And the backslash before the 0 is wrong. `\raisebox{0.2cm}{\includegraphics[]{index_bar.png}}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I also tried `\raisebox{\totalheight}`. The error is still the same: `unrecognized command raisebox`. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @Kristada673: There's also the missing `{}` pair around `\includegraphics[]{...}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Fine, I put the braces; still the same error.

Comment: @Kristada673: No:  `\raisebox{0.2cm}{\includegraphics{index_bar}}`

Comment: Your \raisebox should raise something. And this something is in this case your image. So the (complete) image should be in the second argument of the raisebox command.

Comment: Why do you still have that backslash in front of the vertical shifting? `\-0.2cm` is as wrong as is `\0.2cm`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: What should I write then? I want the picture to be centered inside its cell basically.

Comment: `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{index_bar}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ummm, I don't understand what the mistake here is. When I wrote `\-0.2cm`, the top of the picture is touching the previous `\hline`, and with `{-0.5\height}`, the bottom of the picture is touching the next `\hline`. That's the only difference I can see. Whereas, what I ideally want is there should be an equal gap between the previous `\hline` and the top of the picture, and  between the next`\hline` and the bottom of the picture.

Comment: You've written `\-0.2cm` but that's the macro `\-` followed by `0.2cm`. I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: @TH. But its working. `\-0.2cm` brings it below; `\0.2cm` brings it up.

Comment: Could you please stop to use this backslashes before numbers? It doesn't matter if it perhaps works somehow. It is wrong syntax. Fix lengths are used without backslashes. E.g. {0.2cm} or {5mm} or {-3cm}. Which value is best, depends on your image that we don't have.

Comment: `\-` is for inserting a discretionary hyphen. `\0.2cm` is the same as `\0` followed by `.2cm` and `\0` isn't defined normally so I don't really understand how this can be working for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose, that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

Solution below doesn't solve your issue with `\raisebox` (comments above solve this problem) but rather avoiding them with simple not use it. Instead it are employed packages `adjustbox` (for vertical centering image in cell) and `makecell` (for adding vertical gaps around cells' contents):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}                  % added
\usepackage{makecell}                           % added
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}   % added (from makecell)

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \setcellgapes{\tabcolsep}                   % added (from makecell)
    \makegapedcells                             % added (from makecell)
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline 
\thead{Locale} & \thead{Index}  \\              % changed
            \hline 
Bar & \includegraphics[width=11mm, height=11mm, % determine size of demo imege
                       valign=m]                % added (from adjustbox)
                       {index_bar.png} \\
            \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```